# What is the "Disable Service Factory" option that appears in CF Admin Settings Summary?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-administrator

Creating a new instance in ColdFusion 10 Enterprise with the intention of it matching another instance's settings except some scheduled tasks. When I compare the Settings Summary page output for each instance there is an option called "Disable Service Factory" which I can not find in the admin. The old instance has the setting as "No" and the new instance defaulted to "Yes".

Does anyone know what this option is and how to update it in the admin if necessary? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [security setting](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/configuring-administering/administering-coldfusion-security.html). Disabling it prevents:

> ...the ability for CFML code to access and create Java objects
>   that are part of the internal ColdFusion implementation. This prevents
>   an unauthenticated CFML template from reading or modifying
>   administration and configuration information for this server.

Confusingly, the option is under a totally different name. You can find it under *Server Settings > Settings*:

- [ x ] Disable access to internal ColdFusion Java components

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!.